# Paypal payment create parameters

Tags: paypal, payment

what data can I, should I, must I, place in a create payment body with intent: sale and payment method : paypal?  I specifically am looking for how to detail the one or more items the payment covers. But other useful inclusions would also be welcome.
Thanks

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to send multiple items to paypal you can use `cmd="_cart"` (if using name-value-pair)irrespective of language you use to talk to paypal, but this is not valid in case of REST I guess.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
```

Check this link if helps: [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside)